# Eclipse c++ function is not a class or namespace

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu

I have recently starting using the eclipse IDE on Ubuntu, and I have been struggling with some compilation errors I never experienced on Windows VS Studio. There is what I consider an inexplicable error within the following contents, that eclipse shows as "isStrong is not a class or namespace". I have learned that if you are choosing to write a simple cpp file, it is good practice to declare functions before main, call them in main, and define them afterward. I cannot help wondering if this problem might be the result of a problem with my current configurations of eclipse. All help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isStrong(double height, double weight);

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    cout << "Deez Nuts" << endl;
    bool strong = isStrong(72, 200);
    cout << boolalpha << strong << endl;
    return 0;
}

bool isStrong(double height, double weight) {
    double strengthNum = weight / height;
    if (strengthNum > 2.5) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The program is perfectly fine, it compiles and runs. Is your Eclipse compiling it? The Eclipse's C++ parser may be tricked by something, but nevertheless the program should compile fine.

Comment: its got to be something with the lDE configs. damn, I dont know exactly what it is. Ive done extensive research and tried some things, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: So you cannot even compile it?

Comment: You should compile it and then run it. what is the error? Check the compile settings.

Comment: no, i get an error the "not a class or namespace" in the line with the declaration of double strengthnum in the function definition

Comment: it can run even though there are compiler errors???? never had tried, just assumed it wouldnt run. thanks, but thats weird at the same time